# How to show that $AB=BA$ if $(A-3I)(B-3I)=2B+9I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> How to show $AB=BA$ if: $$(A-3I)(B-3I)=2B+9I$$ where $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$

I've been doing lots of arithmetical transformations but cannot see the way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the fact that an invertible matrix $C$ commutes with its inverse:

$$CC^{-1} = C^{-1}C =I$$

In your case you have:

$$(A-3I)(B-3I) = 2B+9I \Leftrightarrow AB-5B - 3A + 15I = 15I$$

$$\Leftrightarrow (A-5I)(B-3I) = 15 I \Leftrightarrow \frac 1{15}(B-3I) = (A-5I)^{-1}$$
Hence,

$$(B-3I)(A-5I) = (A-5I)(B-3I) = 15 I \Leftrightarrow AB = BA$$

Comment: How do you know $A-5I$ is invertible?

Comment: @ViVID, even by the _Binet Cauchy_: $$\det(A-5I)\det(B-3I)=15$$

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Oh yes, thanks)

Comment: Because we have $(A-5I)(B-3I)=15I$. So, $\det (A-5I)\neq 0$.

Comment: Because apparently $\frac1{15}(B-3I)$ is its inverse